# Models in more than one collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm kinda lost so any help would be much appreciated. (I’m using Backbone.js and CoffeeScript.)

I have a group of models. They are all put in `MasterCollection`.

```coffeescript
MasterCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Model

MasterCollection.add({#attributes of a new model})
```

I need to separate these models at times and process their attributes in batches. These batches also need to have a corresponding DOM view that can show all of the models’ data.

```coffeescript
Model extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: () ->
        #add the model to it's batch, batches are collections stored in an array
        batches = ParentModel.get('baches')

        #find the batch this model belongs in
        for batch in batches
            if batch = #the right one
                batch.add(@toJSON)

Batch extends Backbone.Collection
    changeAttributes: () ->
        for model in @models
            #change things about the model
```

- When this model is changed by the batch, will it update the model in the `MasterCollection`?
- When I’m done with a batch collection, how do I get rid of it without deleting its models?
- Should I store these batch collections in something better than an array? Should they be models?

Since I need the DOM to bind to the creation of new batches, having them as models in a collection would be great.

Is this a good way to do this type of thing overall?

Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm thinking a batch should be a BatchModel with a collection of models in it, thoughts?

Comment: Make batches collections of Models, as well. You can add a model in multiple collections, and it works, its events are broadcasted in all the collections in belongs to. In other works, don't duplicate the data with toJSON, just do batchCollection.add(this)

Answer (score 1):

> When this model is changed by the batch it will update the model in the MasterCollection?

Since you're doing

```
batch.add(@toJSON)
```

you're really just adding a clone of the model to the `batch` collection. So, when you change that collection's model's attributes, the originals won't be affected.

Of course, these are shallow copies, so if you do something like

```
(batch.at(0).get 'attr').x = y
```

you *will* be modifying the `attr` attribute of the original. (You also won't trigger any change events.) This is a no-no with Backbone in general. Instead, do something like

```
attrCopy = _.extend {}, batch.at(0).get 'attr'
attrCopy.x = y
batch.at(0).set attr: attrCopy
```